# Overhead of std::~future?

Tags: c++, future

What's the overhead of destructing `std::future`?
When I was reading [the pdf](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3451.pdf) , it noticed that:

```
// Example 1
// (a)
{
  async( []{ f(); } ); 
  async( []{ g(); } ); 
}
// (b)
{
  auto f1 = async( []{ f(); } );
  auto f2 = async( []{ g(); } );
}
```

> Users are often surprised to discover that (a) and (b) do not have the same behavior, because normally we ignore (and/or don’t look at) return values if we end up deciding we’re not interested in the value and doing so does not change the meaning of our program.

But I checked the difference in the quickbench, , It was the opposite of what I thought. Am I missing any point of the discussion?

https://quick-bench.com/q/L0HtxBWmgvswK7Q90AqOPmsg_F8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Benchmarking

I suspect `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms)` to be the culprit here. Putting a thread to sleep and waking it up again is not a very precise operation. Sometimes a thread is woken up a little earlier, sometimes too early, so it has to be put back to sleep. If you [remove the sleep](https://quick-bench.com/q/RtAqpxn2GELJdbmzLWAv7Vb2LQA) (or use a [deterministic operation](https://quick-bench.com/q/0LVG__jQ1ynuhNCK8n9okYxYwcM) instead), you can see that they're basically identical.

## The `async` Issue

Skimming the PDF, the issue Herb is talking about, is if you chain multiple async calls, they might execute differently depending on whether you assign the future to a variable. The future's destructor is still run in all scenarios, just at different points in time. Remember that C++ cannot distinguish a function overload based on return type. That means, no matter if you use the return value or not, it will still be constructed and therefore has to be destructed. The only difference is when the destruction happens.

Scenario (a) is different, because both async calls happen synchronously, since the future is destroyed immediately, which blocks the thread:

```
{
    async( []{ f(); } ); 
    // ^ this future is a temporary, it will be destroyed here, directly after the function call

    async( []{ g(); } );
    // ^ this future is a temporary, it will be destroyed here, directly after the function call
}
```

Scenario (b) on the other hand, both async calls can happen before either future is destroyed, because both futures only ever get destroyed **after both** async calls happened.

```
{
    auto f1 = async( []{ f(); } );
    auto f2 = async( []{ g(); } ); 
}
// ^ variables went out of scope here, both futures will be destroyed now
```

Answer (score 4):

The point of the PDF is that when you do:

```
async( []{ f(); } ); 
async( []{ g(); } );
```

The hidden destructor of the future after each `async` call makes the current thread wait for `async` to complete, thereby making the code synchronous. i.e the code does:

1. launch task1
2. wait for task1
3. launch task2
4. wait for task2

Changing to:

```
auto f1 = async( []{ f(); } );
auto f2 = async( []{ g(); } );
```

Both tasks are launched before the futures destruct allowing the tasks to run in parallel (assuming `std::async` is actually using multiple threads).

Your benchmark only runs a single task in each loop and therefore doesn't demonstrate this problem. I imagine most of the difference in your results come from the randomness of `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.

Changing the benchmark to have two tasks does show a small difference: https://quick-bench.com/q/wy6yPq4yMBi_VGSJ7HI_hLccZmc (though again it might just be within the margin of error). I'm not sure that the quickbench website even offers multiple CPUs?